# How to extract data in columns from page using soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests

Trying to capture data which is present in bullet points

link https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/

need to extract the data using xpath here

data to be extracted

```
    4 Door Sedan

    4 Cylinder, 1.8 Litre

    Constantly Variable Transmission, Front Wheel Drive

    Petrol - Unleaded ULP

    6.4 L/100km
```

tried this :

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import html
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


cars = [] 

urls = ['https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/']

for url in urls: 
    car_data={} 
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    if tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div'):
        car_data["namings"] = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported BeautifulSoup so why not use css class selector?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
info = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.dgi-')]
```

[image]

You could also print as

```
for i in soup.select('.dgi-'):
    print(i.text.strip())
```

Comment: if i need to strip the output into 5 parts ?. like door = 4 door sedan, body = 4 cylinder, 1.8 litre

Comment: the output is in parts. It is a list.

Comment: I have added an edit so you can see how to print without list comprehension

Comment: how to assign each element of a list to a variable.    it tried to do this                                 `info = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.dgi-')]
    car_data['0']=info.split(" ")[0]
    car_data['1']=info.split(" ")[1]
    car_data['2']=info.split(" ")[2]
    car_data['3']=info.split(" ")[3]  `

Answer (score 0):

- [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)-returns a collection of elements.
- [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)- in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

**Ex.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cars = []
urls = ['https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208/']

for url in urls:
    car_data=[]
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
    car_obj = soup.find("div",{'class':'r-center-pane'}).find("div",\
                    {'class':'micro-spec'}).find("div",{'class':'columns'}).find_all("dd")

    for x in car_obj:
        text = x.text.strip()
        if text != "":
            car_data.append(text)
    cars.append(car_data)

print(cars)
```

**O/P:**

```
[['4 Door Sedan', '4 Cylinder, 1.8 Litre', 'Constantly Variable Transmission,
Front Wheel Drive', 'Petrol - Unleaded ULP', '6.4 L/100km']]
```